# Webpack, Angular 4, Jasmine, ES2015 - platformBrowserDynamicTesting is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, jasmine

I'm evaluating Angular 4 (we currently use Angular 1.5) and have got Webpack and Angular 4 setup and working using ES2015 **not** TypeScript. My build works and I can view the output in a browser without any issues.

I'm now trying to add Karma and Jasmine with a basic unit test, but I am seeing the following error when trying to run the test:

> Uncaught TypeError: _platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamicTesting is not a function

The error originates from the test-main.js file (see below), not from the .spec.js file.

I've been using one of the [official guides](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#!#test-configuration) to get everything setup, but something is not quite right. The guide is for TypeScript, and I want to use ES2015, but I can't see that I'm missing anything huge from the guide.

When I run the tests, I get output that Webpack is compiling, and that it compiled successfully, and I see output for Karma starting, and the Chrome headless browser launching, but then I see the error above.

I've tried commenting the line that causes the error, but in this case the error changes to

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'injector' of null

Here are the relevant files:

*karma.conf.js*:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
           { pattern: './Static/test/test-main.js' }
        ],
        exclude: [],
        preprocessors: { './Static/test/test-main.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'] },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadless: {
                base: 'Chrome',
                flags: ['--headless', ' --remote-debugging-port=9222', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-plugins', '--window-size=0,0', '--window-position=-9999,0'],
            },
        },
        singleRun: true,
        concurrency: Infinity,
        webpack: {
            module: {
                rules: [{
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                    }]
                }]
            },
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            plugins: [
               new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, './Static/js')
            ]
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        webpackServer: {
            noInfo: true
        }
    });
}
```

*test-main.js*:

```
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';

import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

let appContext = require.context('./js', true, /\.spec\.js/);

appContext.keys().forEach(appContext);

TestBed.initTestEnvironment(platformBrowserDynamic.BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
```

*app.welcome.spec.js*:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {WelcomeComponent} from '../../js/app.welcome';

describe('The Welcome component', function () {

    let component;

    beforeEach(function() {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [WelcomeComponent]
        });

        let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WelcomeComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be a component', function() {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a function indeed, because the import is wrong. Testing things aren't being put in the same pile as production things in Angular. It is `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing`, not `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`.

The actual code will look like

```
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

...
TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
...
```

See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9xEB6myPEtXMmLYMXpHu?p=preview) as working example of how it is done.

Comment: thanks,I tried changing it in my test-main.js file (I'm not using TypeScript), but the error has just changed to `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _platformBrowserDynamic.platformBrowserDynamicTesting) is not a function` ?

Comment: It doesn't look like you applied all suggested changes. Considering that it says `_platformBrowserDynamic`, it looks like you're still trying to import it from `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`.

Comment: >< You are correct - I forgot to add the `/testing` to the end of `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic`. Well spotted, thank you. It's working now